# How to call function in parent class component by onchange event from child component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component which fires function `pageChange` when I press `2` button in the pagination bar:

```
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Pagination } from "antd";

const Child = props => {
  function pageChange(pageNumber) {
    props.pageChange(pageNumber);
    console.log("Page child: ", pageNumber);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Pagination
        defaultCurrent={1}
        total={50}
        onChange={pageChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Child;
```

This child is used in the Parent class component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Child from "./Child";

class Parent extends Component {
  state = {
    pageIndex: 3
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getSetData(this.state.pageIndex);
  }

  getSetData(pageNumber) {
    this.setState({
      pageIndex: 5
    });
    console.log("Page state: ", this.state.pageIndex);
    console.log("pageNumber: ", pageNumber);
  }

  pageChange(pageNumber) {
    console.log("Page parent: ", pageNumber);
    this.getSetData(pageNumber);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Child pageChange={this.pageChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

But I have troubles with it:

1. When I press `2` button I get an error `this.getSetData is not a function`. How to call `getSetData` from `pageChange`?
2. Statement `this.setState({pageIndex: 9});` do not works during `componentDidMount` call. Why?

**SOLVED**

1. As far as I understand a function without an arrow has its own `this`. So one must use

```
pageChange = pageNumber => {
    this.getSetData(pageNumber);
  };
```

instead of

```
pageChange(pageNumber) {
    this.getSetData(pageNumber);
  }
```

2. `setState` is async, so to see change in console is useful to call from `render`

```
  render() {
    console.log("render ", this.state.pageIndex);
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Child pageChange={this.pageChange} />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: You need to bind the function to 'this', you can read more about it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy solution can be, using ES6 functions. So you don't need to bind that in constructor

```
 getSetData = (pageNumber) => {
    this.setState({
      pageIndex: 5
    });
    console.log("Page state: ", this.state.pageIndex);
    console.log("pageNumber: ", pageNumber);
  }
```

**EDIT 1**

Try using your child component like this.

`<Child pageChange={() => this.pageChange()} />`

[Running Example](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-antonelli-5yguy)

**EDIT 2**

```
<Child pageChange={(e) => this.pageChange(e)} />
```

You didn't pass the parameter to pagechange function that's why it didn't recieve anything.

Try this it will surely work. I have tested this in your code.

Comment: This gives the same error, in this case `getSetData` looks like a class property, not a function.

Comment: @MDspb Check Edit 1

Comment: Edit 1 ruins link with `pageChange` method and makes `pageNumber` undefined

Answer (score 1):

May be you need to bind the function with `this`  to use `this.setState`.
See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) for more

```
class Parent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // binding here
    this.state = {
      pageIndex: 3
    };
    this.getSetData = this.getSetData.bind(this);
    this.getSetDataArrow = this.getSetDataArrow.bind(this);
    this.pageChange = this.pageChange.bind(this);
  }
  state = {
    // items: [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b: 4 }],
    pageIndex: 3
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getSetDataArrow(this.state.pageIndex);
    this.getSetData(this.state.pageIndex);
  }

  getSetData(pageNumber) {
    this.setState({
      pageIndex: 5
    });
    console.log("Page state: ", this.state.pageIndex);
    console.log("pageNumber: ", pageNumber);
  }
  getSetDataArrow = pageNumber => {
    this.setState({
      pageIndex: 4
    });
    console.log("Page state: ", this.state.pageIndex);
    console.log("pageNumber: ", pageNumber);
  };

  pageChange(pageNumber) {
    console.log("Page parent: ", pageNumber);
    // this.setState({
    //   pageIndex: 9
    // });
    // this.setState is not a function
    this.getSetDataArrow(pageNumber);
    this.getSetData(pageNumber);
    // this.getSetData is not a function
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <Child pageChange={this.pageChange} />
        {/* <Child pageChange={this.pageChange} items={this.state.items} /> */}
        {/* <Child2 pageChange={this.pageChange} /> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

export default Parent;

Comment: Unfortunately this do not help, I have the same error when code has constructor binding

Comment: can you post the exact error or the error screenshot?

Comment: Also did you try putting the state inside the constructor as in the answer above ?2

Comment: [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/silly-albattani-ugeju?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Does not help (defining state in constructor)

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-darkness-dnzdq?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark -I have updated the code and its working please check @MDspb

Comment: Strange but `this.state.pageIndex` and `pageNumber` have different values: Page state Arrow:  
3
pageNumber Arrow:  
3
Page state:  
3
pageNumber:  
3
Page child:  
2
Page parent:  
2
Page state Arrow:  
5
pageNumber Arrow:  
2
Page state:  
5
pageNumber:  
2 Also `this.setState({pageIndex: 4});` does not sets 4 to the state.

Comment: And `this.state.pageIndex` does not change value to 2

Comment: Might be some logical issue you have